# how to translate and scale a NSImage?

Tags: cocoa, translate, nsimage, nsimageview, nsaffinetransform

I have built so far an application that allows the user to drag and drop images onto a NSImageView. However, I want to be able to move these images by simply clicking on any image and hold down the mouse button to move it's location.

How can I manipulate NSImageView to translate/scale after setting the images down? Is that possible? I've read about the NSAffineTransform, but it seems like that is moving the images before creating the image itself. I already have the images on the canvas, and simply want to click and hold the image and move it with my mouse. Please help anyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two sides to this.

**`NSImage`** is the model object, which you might want to display in different ways, save to disk/archive, etc.  If you want to actually change the *model* (scaling, rotating, etc.), implying a permanent change, then you are going to probably want to look at `NSAffineTransform`, Quartz drawing, etc.

But you probably didn't mean that.  Instead you probably are interested in **`NSImageView`**, which is a view object, displaying the contents of the `NSImage` model object using whatever display attributes are desired.  If you only want to change how an image is displayed, not what the actual bytes in the image are, then you are going to manipulate the `NSImageView` at run-time.  You can use `NSAffineTransform` here as well, but it's somewhat uncommon (and usually unnecessary).

The key thing to note that is the `NSImageView` inherits from [`NSView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html), so you have all its power at your disposal.  Take a look at certain methods, such as:

`-setFrameSize:` - useful for changing the view size, and thus the image display scale

`-setFrameOrigin:` - useful for changing the view position, and thus the apparent image position

Note again that these have nothing to do with images per se, and apply to all Cocoa views.  You may want to take a look at a book like [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774086) to get you past the basics.  (You can then do more interesting things, like rotation, animation, etc.)

Comment: @ObjectiveC-InLearning Glad to be of help!